# Iterative printing of a tree model

Tags: python, tree, iteration

I have a tree of nodes like this:

```
class Node:
    next        # the next node or None
    prev        # the previous node or None
    parent      # the parent or None
    children[]  # ordered list of child nodes
    columns[]   # a list of data. Currently only holdt the 
                # string representation of the node in the model.
```

Since I can't know in advance how large the model is, I've reached the conclusion that recursion is not an option. I would like to keep as few nodes in memory as possible. This is what my method should print:

```
- 0
-- 0:0
--- 0:0:0
--- 0:0:1
---- 0:0:1:0
---- 0:0:1:1
--- 0:0:2
-- 0:1
- 1
```

But this is what it *does* print:

```
- 0
-- 0:0
-- 0:1
-- 0
- 1
--- 0:0:0
--- 0:0:1
--- 0:0:2
-- 0:1
-- 0
- 1
--- 0:0:1
---- 0:0:1:0
---- 0:0:1:1
--- 0:0:2
-- 0
---- 0:0:1:0
---- 0:0:1:1
--- 0:0:2
---- 0:0:1:1
---- 0:0:1:1
```

Here's the code I've written:

```
def print_tree(from_path):
    nodelist = []
    root_node = model.get_iter(from_path)
    nodelist.append((root_node, 0)) # the second item in the tuple is the indentation

    while nodelist:
        node = nodelist[0][0]
        indent = nodelist[0][1]
        del(nodelist[0])
        print("{0} {1}".format("-" * indent, node.columns[0])) 

        if node.children:
            child = node.children[0]
            nodelist.append((child, indent +1))

            while child.next:
                nodelist.append((child.next, indent +1))
                child = child.next
        if node.next:
            next = node.next
            nodelist.append((next, indent))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `next` and `prev`? Siblings?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each node has a reference to its parent, I think you can traverse the whole tree keeping only one node in memory at a time. I had a bit of trouble understanding your code (in particular how each node is loaded to memory), so I'll post my suggestion in pseudo-code:

```
def visit(node,indent):
    # Load your node data
    print("{0} {1}".format("-" * indent, node.columns[0])) # Do something with your data
    # Unload your node data
    if len(node.children) > 0 :
        return (node.children[0], indent+1) # Visit the first child, if there is one
    while node.next is None: # If no sibling, your parent is done
        node = node.parent
        indent -= 1
        if node is None: # Root node reached, end the traversal
            return None
    return (node.next, indent) # Visit your next sibling, if there is one

cursor = (root_node, 0)
while cursor is not None:
    cursor = visit(*cursor)
```

If the node itself must be dynamically loaded (i.e. `next`, `prev`, `parent` and `children` only contain the path to another node's data, not a reference to a `Node` object), tell me and I'll update the answer (just need to change a little the places for loading/unloading). Of course, if unloading is just a matter of leaving the object to the garbage collector, it's even easier...

Comment: @jo-erlend my code is not recursive, the only function definition is `visit` and it never calls itself... and sorry if I misunderstood your question, when you said "I would like to keep as few nodes in memory as possible" I couldn't imagine you meant **in the stack**. Just leave those two comments blank and you're fine (since my code is not recursive, only one node will be in the stack in any given moment).

Comment: That's nice! I don't really understand how it works yet, but it does and I'll figure it out. All abstract algorithms I've seen uses lists to store queues of nodes to be visited, but that doesn't seem to be necessary with your code. I'm really looking forward to testing it out thoroughly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

As mgibsonbr notes, since you're storing a parent pointer, it's possible to do this iteratively while tracking only the current node (and its indent):

```
def print_tree(from_path):

    node, indent = model.get_iter(from_path), 0

    while node:

        if indent:           # don't print the root
            print "-" * indent, node.columns[0]

        if node.children:    # walk to first child before walking to next sibling
            node = node.children[0]
            indent += 1
        elif node.next:      # no children, walk to next sibling if there is one
            node = node.next
        else:
            # no children, no more siblings: find closet ancestor w/ more siblings
            # (note that this might not be the current node's immediate parent)
            while node and not node.next:
                node = node.parent
                indent -= 1
            node = node and node.next
```

You can turn this into a generator by replacing the `print` line with `yield indent, node`.

I had to mock up some test data to debug this. Here's what I've got, in case anyone else wants to play. I treated the root as not being able to have siblings (there's no reason it couldn't have a `next` and store data in `columns`, but then you'd want your indents to start at 1).

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, sib=None, value=""):
        self.parent   = parent
        self.prev     = sib
        self.next     = None
        self.children = []
        self.columns  = [str(value)]
    def child(self, value):
        child = Node(self, None, value)
        if self.children:
            self.children[-1].next = child
            child.prev = self.children[-1]
        self.children.append(child)
        return child
    def sib(self, value):
        return self.parent.child(value)

class model(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_iter(_):

        root = Node()

        root.child("0").child("0:0").child("0:0:0").sib("0:0:1") \
            .child("0:0:1:0").sib("0:0:1:0").parent.sib("0:0:2")
        root.children[0].child("0:1").parent.sib("1")

        return root
```

Comment: liked that answer, cleaner than mine. But I think the last `else` needs another `while` - see what would happen when the parent has no siblings but the grandparent does.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! :) This is all very exciting to me and I've been stuck at this point for a while, so now I can have some progress again! Very grateful :)

Comment: This was a bit of an exercise for me -- I've always done this recursively. But it was fun, thanks for the challenge!